# Multiple monitors on Intel HD graphics both duplicate and extended displays

Tags: windows-7, drivers, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-graphics

I have a Lenovo W540 running Windows 7, which has both the Intel HD 4600 graphics (primary) and an Nvidia Quadro K1100M card using Nvidia's Optimus driver. The displays are run through the HD driver.

I have 4 monitors. I want to set up two of them as duplicate and the other two as extended. However, I cannot do this. The HD graphics control panel doesn't have an option to allow that, and when I try using the windows screen resoution dialog, I get the error "Unable to save display settings"

I have attempted to use the Nvidia card as the primary display driver without success (disabling the HD graphics, reinstalling the Nvidia driver, etc), but the Optimus driver is designed to work in the background behind another graphics system (so far as I can tell).

Any thoughts on how to get my desired display setup working correctly?

Comment: Does it work if you only try to duplicate one display.  I am pretty sure Windows is getting confused by trying to determine which displays you want duplicated.  Its very likely what you want isn't possible.

Comment: I've been trying to get just three to work to start with--two duplicated and one extended, which doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have had all sorts of "quirks" supporting Dell Latitudes with similar hardware to what you describe (Intel 4600 + Nvidia).  Mirror + Extend configurations have never worked in my experience.

Since the Lenovo W540 is a laptop, how are the displays connected? Through a docking station?

In my Dell experience, I've found that the two digital connections on the dock correspond to nVidia, and the VGA connection goes to Intel HD graphics.  You may try extending across one graphics chipset and mirroring on the other.

Comment: Very interesting idea. Yes, I am using a dock, but it appears that all connections go to Intel HD. I haven't tried the thunderbolt port on the laptop itself yet--I'll see if I can get an adapter and try that.

Answer (score -1):

Disable Hyper V as per information on the intel site
https://communities.intel.com/thread/110642